# Unmarshal JSON into struct

Tags: json, struct, go, google-apps-script

My issue is very small but very frustrating since I can't seem to get the answer. I am trying to access the JSON part of a response from Google Script. In Golang, I have managed to strip it down to this

```
map[@type:type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse result:[
{
    "id": 1,
    "casenumber": "Criminal Case 20 of 2012",
    "datedelivered": "2015-10-22T21:00:00.000Z",
    "judge": "George Matatia Abaleka Dulu",
    "court": "High Court",
    "location": "Garissa",
    "accused": "Abdi Sheikh Mohamed",
    "judgment": "The accused Abdi Sheikh Mohamed stands charged with the offence of murder contrary to Section 203 as read with Section 204 of the Penal Code.  The particulars of the offence are that on 8th May 2012 at Ifo Refugee camp, Lagdera District within Garissa County murdered Othon Ubang Alwal.  He has denied the charge."
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "casenumber": "Criminal Case 21 of 2012",
    "datedelivered": "2015-11-22T21:00:00.000Z",
    "judge": "Lilo",
    "court": "High Court",
    "location": "Nairobi",
    "accused": "Stitch",
    "prosecution": "Milo",
    "judgment": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
}
]]
```

but I need to strip it down one level further by getting rid of

```
map[@type:type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse result:[
```

so I only have the results part.

So far I have tried unmarshalling it to my struct with no success. Here is the struct

```
type Case struct {
    ID int            
    CaseNumber string 
    DateDelivered string 
    Judge string 
    Court string 
    Location string                                   
    Accused string 
    Prosecution string 
    Judgment string
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** What I meant by the unmarshaling part is that when I try unmarshaling into my struct (even after fixing the struct) I get the error

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []Case
```

This is the code I need to get to work http://play.golang.org/p/rmsvfPVx52.

Comment: When you say that you tried unmarshalling with no success, can provide more details. Also can you show your code that will help to understand what you are trying. As of now I see for Case struct except for ID all other fields are not exposed has they are not starting with capital letters and while unmarshalling they will not be populated.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I had not noticed. Please check the edit on the question. I have used it to answer your question :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields in Case by starting the name with an uppercase character.

```
type Case struct {
  ID int            
  CaseNumber string 
  DateDelivered string 
  Judge string 
  Court string 
  Location string                                   
  Accused string 
  Prosecution string 
  Judgment string
}
```

The encoding/json package and similar packages ignore unexported fields.

Use a slice to decode a JSON array:

```
  var result []Case
  err := json.Unmarshal(data, &result)
  if err != nil {
     // handle error
  }
```

<kbd>[Playground Example](http://play.golang.org/p/IzMEHXQ0a7)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I bet this solution would work if I could find a way to strip 

`map[@type:type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse result:[` 

automatically using code and not manually. I might be wrong though :(. But take a look at this please http://play.golang.org/p/rmsvfPVx52

Comment: The text `map[@type:type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse` is not valid JSON.  You will need to strip in manually if the server is in fact returning invalid JSON.

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was an automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Where `c` is

```
map[@type:type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse result:[
{
"id": 1,
"casenumber": "Criminal Case 20 of 2012",
"datedelivered": "2015-10-22T21:00:00.000Z",
"judge": "George Matatia Abaleka Dulu",
"court": "High Court",
"location": "Garissa",
"accused": "Abdi Sheikh Mohamed",
"judgment": "The accused Abdi Sheikh Mohamed stands charged with the offence of murder contrary to Section 203 as read with Section 204 of the Penal Code.  The particulars of the offence are that on 8th May 2012 at Ifo Refugee camp, Lagdera District within Garissa County murdered Othon Ubang Alwal.  He has denied the charge."
},
{
"id": 2,
"casenumber": "Criminal Case 21 of 2012",
"datedelivered": "2015-11-22T21:00:00.000Z",
"judge": "Lilo",
"court": "High Court",
"location": "Nairobi",
"accused": "Stitch",
"prosecution": "Milo",
"judgment": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
}
]]
```

I did;

```
case:= c.(map[string]interface {})
fmt.Println(case["result"])
```

which gives;

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "casenumber": "Criminal Case 20 of 2012",
    "datedelivered": "2015-10-22T21:00:00.000Z",
    "judge": "George Matatia Abaleka Dulu",
    "court": "High Court",
    "location": "Garissa",
    "accused": "Abdi Sheikh Mohamed",
    "judgment": "The accused Abdi Sheikh Mohamed stands charged with the offence of murder contrary to Section 203 as read with Section 204 of the Penal Code.  The particulars of the offence are that on 8th May 2012 at Ifo Refugee camp, Lagdera District within Garissa County murdered Othon Ubang Alwal.  He has denied the charge."
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "casenumber": "Criminal Case 21 of 2012",
    "datedelivered": "2015-11-22T21:00:00.000Z",
    "judge": "Lilo",
    "court": "High Court",
    "location": "Nairobi",
    "accused": "Stitch",
    "prosecution": "Milo",
    "judgment": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CodingPickle indicated above, you need to strip the non-valid json first:

```
data := `{"result":[
{
    "id": 1,
    ...
},
{
    "id": 2,
    ...
}]}`
```

As well, you need to add the json defn's to the struct:

```
type Result struct {
    Result []Case `json:"result"`
}

type Case struct {
    ID            int    `json:"id"`
    CaseNumber    string `json:"casenumber"`
    DateDelivered string `json:"datedelivered"`
    Judge         string `json:"judge"`
    Court         string `json:"court"`
    Location      string `json:"location"`
    Accused       string `json:"accused"`
    Prosecution   string `json:"prosecution"`
    Judgment      string `json:"judgement"`
}
```

Example:

http://play.golang.org/p/KUbDpSxMVI